# Use variable as parameter key Javascript/Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a bit of code that looks like this:

```
var selectedValue = event.currentTarget.value;
var selectTarget = event.currentTarget.id;
Backbone.sync('read', this.collection, {data: $.param({selectTarget: selectedValue })});
```

Both `selectTarget` and `selectedValue` need to be variables. After a little research, I learned that I can't pass a variable as a parameter key. However, I can't figure out how to restructure my code to get around this problem. Is there a way to build the Backbone.sync call so that I can pass variables for both the key and the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the object first and set the property using the index syntax:

```
var param = {};
param[selectTarget] = selectedValue;
Backbone.sync('read', this.collection, {data: $.param(param)});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var paramObject = {};
paramObject[selectTarget] = selectedValue;

$.param(paramObject);
```